# Is there limits with Ionic Framework mobile app?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, native-code, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm learning how to code a android mobile app with Ionic Framework because I want to create a todo list with a bubble like Facebook Messenger, that is able to send task to workmates, a chronometer  and something more but I don't know if with Ionic I will can do it and if is not if I will need programming all of my app again with native or not because if it is then it'd be better programming with native right now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much everything available on a native app is also possible to do with Ionic. HTML5 constructs give you universal layout flexibility, and device APIs are available through Cordova.

That said, the Facebook chat heads uses a lower-level Android API, and as there isn't currently a Cordova plugin for that, you'd need to develop one. This would take more development time than just going native.

Also, it's understandable that you're opting for hybrid development for the enormous time savings in having code that works across platforms. But, as far as I know, Facebook chatheads is a feature that only works on Android. And if Android is your only release target, it makes sense to just go native.

Comment: Please describe how you would implement Facebook chatheads with anything other than Android's native APIs.

Comment: You mean the icons that display next to users' names? I think those are exposed with the Graph API

Comment: There's also a [Facebook Cordova plugin](http://plugreg.com/plugin/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) so you can use Single Sign On.

Comment: What about to add a bubble like Facebook Messenger?

Comment: @user2779883 Hmm I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that. Are you talking about the chat-bubble shape of messages on the screen? (Like in [this](https://lh5.ggpht.com/dH_Znb__NjJkyQ0_HW4TPniO3pnfXqhVF9xQ2r06bj_z0PGXIKIIxw0GlvDmKWYUDw=h900-rw) screenshot)

Comment: I mean, for example a bubble that float in the screen that when you click on it, this bubble open the app and add a task for a todo list for example and also can be configures the block screen in order to when you turn on the blocked screen there is a button in what you can press a button a add a task with the voice using the API of Google.

Comment: As far as speech recognition goes, that can be handled by Cordova plugins. Choose any of [these](http://plugreg.com/search?q=speech). I'm still unclear on what you mean by bubbles. Do you perhaps want an Android homescreen widget? Or a push notification?

Comment: @Jamie He and I are talking about Facebook chat heads... as in floating windows that are able to draw on top of other applications. I doubt that third party frameworks like Cordova are able to do that.

Comment: Exactly, I mean the same as @Alex say, a bubble that it's floating on top of other applications and when you click that, this open the app for a easier way tu add task when you are in one application and you don't want to close the app and make a click in a widget or button, then add the task, close the todo list and finally open again the first application. It work better when a bubble and you don't need to close the current app.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that existed. I don't think there's an existing Cordova plugin for that - but I don't think it would be impossible to make one. Essentially you'd just make a wrapper around Android's `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`. [Here's](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/) a good blog post on how to go about this

Comment: @user2779883 Why are you interested in using a third party framework like Cordova in the first place? It sounds like you are better off using the native Android SDK... you will find a ton of documentation and help online if you choose to go native.