# is there a facebook chat heads implementation for ionic or cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

Did any one have solution for creating facebook chat heads kind implementation in ionic or cordova.

The only answer which i found is:

> the Facebook chat heads uses a lower-level Android API, and as there isn't currently a Cordova plugin for that, you'd need to develop one. This would take more development time than just going native. [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25393762)

Also, it's understandable that you're opting for hybrid development for the enormous time savings in having code that works across platforms. But, as far as I know, Facebook chatheads is a feature that only works on Android. And if Android is your only release target, it makes sense to just go native.

Answer (score 1):

[The Microsoft Ace plugin](http://microsoft.github.io/ace/) for Cordova provides APIs that allow for building features like this.

There's sadly no documentation on how to build Android overlays with the plugin right now so it'll take a bit of work to figure that part out, but it definitely seems to be possible.

http://microsoft.github.io/ace/

(Comment originally posted here [Facebook Chatheads in a Phonegap app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37882004/facebook-chatheads-in-a-phonegap-app/40188006#40188006))

Comment: the project is dead